# I am using the .grid command but its not lined up correctly and is not straight

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a program that makes a calculator with a GUI and I'm using tkinter but when I use the .grid command and assign it to a column it doesn't line up correctly and there is a bit of a gap between them... I am using python 3.7. Any ideas please.

I have tried using the grid and pack commands. I know there is the place method but not sure the exact co-ordinates I have to use so any idea on how to use the grid method correctly.

```
from tkinter import *
#from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")


#========================Screen=======================
Display = Entry(root, fg='white', bg='green', 
    justify='right', bd=25)
Display.grid(columnspan=4)

#=======================Row1==========================
b7 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='7').grid(row=1, column=0)
b8 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='8').grid(row=1, column=1)
b9 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='9').grid(row=1, column=2)
clear = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='C', highlightbackground='green', highlightthickness=0.1).grid(row=1, column=3)

#=======================Row2==========================
b4 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='4').grid(row=2, column=0)
b5 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='5').grid(row=2, column=1)
b6 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='6').grid(row=2, column=2)
plus = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='+', highlightbackground='orange', highlightthickness=0.1).grid(row=2, column=3)

#=======================Row3==========================
b1 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='1').grid(row=3, column=0)
b2 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='2').grid(row=3, column=1)
b3 = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='3').grid(row=3, column=2)
minus = Button(root, padx=30, pady=15, bd=8, fg='black', text='-', highlightbackground='orange', highlightthickness=0.1).grid(row=3, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

I want the C, + and - to be lined up in the same column

[image: here is the GUI as it stands]

Comment: It lines up for me. I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.7

Comment: Having said that, I'm guessing that adding `sticky='NSEW'` to all your `grid` calls will help. Without it, the size of the buttons is based on the contents, with it the button is stretched to fill the row and column.

Comment: Just add it as an extra argument in the grid call like: `grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW')`. Do that for all your buttons.